# Django filter_horizontal - how to connect more fields together

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, many-to-many

I need to connect more fields to one `filter_horizontal` parameter in Django Admin as string. I have three many-to-many variables:

```
class EducationTypeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
...
list_filter = ("qualifications", "school_levels", "subject_groups")
filter_horizontal = ["qualifications", "subject_groups", "school_levels"]
```

This code will make 3 seperate many-to-many horizontal filters. I need them to be in one.
Ex in admin:

```
AS, English, High School -->
```

Main thing is that I need to configure the string in the box. Sorry for my weird explanation, but if you have any questions, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was little confused how it works but all what I needed to do was overwrite the `__str__` function under the qualifications.